# Java: Why is there no String#containsIgnoreCase?

Tags: java

Since years I'm wondering why there is no method `containsIgnoreCase` in the class `String`. We have `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase`, but there is only `contains` and no `containsIgnoreCase`. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: You can write your own method to do it pretty easily.

Comment: I don't think this question can reasonably be answered, unless one of the original language architects happens to be on SO.

Comment: All the IgnoreCase methods are arguably broken -- the definition of "ignoring case" is really subtle, especially when you get to fancier Unicode stuff.  Use ICU4J or something like that.

Comment: There was no `String.contains` method at all prior to Java 5...

Comment: Apache Commons has that covered: [`StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really impossible to say what the exact reason was. Perhaps it was felt that `equals` would be used more frequently than `contains` and so it would prove most useful to implement an `equalsIgnoreCase` method, but not all that useful to implement `containsIgnoreCase`. In any case, it's hard to be sure. Having said that, you can indeed easily implement your own method in terms of the original `contains` method, something along these lines could work:

```
String s1 = "HeLlO WoRlD";
String s2 = "llo worl";
System.out.println(s1.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase()));  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods in String class, which are potential candidates for **IgnoreCase** like **indexOf, lastIndexOf, startsWith, EndWith** etc..

But I think, **toUpperCase** and **toLowerCase** will make IgnoreCase methods obsolete one day, that could be the reason.